# Как сформировать json запрос с помошью fetch метода к api?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

Подскажите пожалуйста.

В примере к api показан такой пример.

```
https://api.example.ru/v1/customers/login.json

{
   "appkey": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
   "login": "info@info.ru",
   "password": "Password1"
}
```

У меня есть все параметры.

Как мне сформировать запрос к апи используя  fetch ?
Я не могу понять куда параметры и как вписывать ? 
Не указанно это POST или GET запрос.

Comment: Может ссылку на описание api банка или кого там?

Comment: https://dev.dellin.ru/api/catalogs/places/

Почта )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fetch("https://api.example.ru/v1/customers/login.json", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: [
    ["Content-Type", "application/json"],
    ["Content-Type", "text/plain"]
  ],
  credentials: "include",
  body: JSON.stringify(your_data)
});
```

Должно быть как-то так. Обычно тестовые данные можно засылать на такие сервисы для проверки, но здесь не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно зарегистрироваться на ДЛ разработчиках и ДЛ личный кабинет логин, пароль из ЛК ключ из разработчиков.

Библиотеки здесь https://github.com/Niklan/PHP-Dellin-API-SDK

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
include($root . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use Niklan\DellinApi\Client\HttpClient;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Auth\AppkeyAuth;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Auth\SessionAuth;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Auth\AuthInterface;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Request\RequestInterface;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Request\Auth\Login;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Response\Response;
use Niklan\DellinApi\Response\ResponseInterface;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;


$auth = new AppkeyAuth('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000');

$client = new HttpClient($auth);

$request = new Login('Login' , 'Pass');
$response = $client->execute($request);
$result = $response->getResult();


$auth = new SessionAuth('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', $result['sessionID']);
$client = new HttpClient($auth);



$response = $client->request('/v3/public/terminals', ['login' => 'Login', 'password' => 'Pass']);
$result = $response->getResult ();
print_r($result);
```